# Running subprocess module assigned to os environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a problem with my python script and after trying/searching for hours I haven't found the solution yet. So I'm seeking your help.

I'm running a subprocess call from inside a software which has a python interpreter builtin. As this python interpreter doesn't have the required python modules I'm assigning this subprocess to the main OS default environment. This subprocess is basically a service that opens a given port and acept tcp connections to that port.

```
 _sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 needed_value=['python','service.py']
 enviro = #a dictionary with os.enviro I got from terminal
 engine_osx =subprocess.Popen(needed_value,shell=None,env=enviro)
```

So this is basically the python script. Problem is that, afterwards, I have a while loop which tries to connect to the open port and it always fail. However if I use telnet, I can connect to the port (even during the while loop).
Moreover, If I restart the script (I have a condition not to start the subprocess again if it is already running), I can associate with no issues.

```
  _sock.connect((str(server_ip), port))
```

So my question is, why is it not connecting at the first attempt? I don't know if it is relevant but I'm using OSX (doesn't happen in windows or linux).

Many thanks

Comment: Are you getting a return value from standard output or your socket?

Comment: Just a try / except inside the cycle with _sock.connect() if the sockets fails to connect I'll enter the except and continue the loop. If it connects, I break the loop

Comment: I see. Does it always succeed on the second attempt?

Comment: `shell=None` is obsolete (and inaccurate), `shell=False` is the default. As for the question it probably tries to connect too fast, before the listening socket is set up. Quickest fix to verify this is to add a delay before connection attempt.

Comment: Thanks for both comments. It always succeed to connect at 2nd attempt. Shell is in fact defined to False in my latest version. And I've a delay of 1 second after starting the subprocess. I'll increase that to 5 seconds and see if there is any improvements

Comment: The delay doesn't solve the problem :/